# How to get out PNG button white shadow

Tags: html, css

I have this button (wood) when a complile my page :

[on page load button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr5V0.jpg)

After click on this button it has some white shadow:

[after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVyRq.jpg)

And when i click and press button, it has like gray shadow:

How can i delete this shadows?

```css
.btn-enter {
    background: url(../images/plank-36736_960_720.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 24%;
    width:55%;
    height: 20%;
    border:none;
    background-color:none;

}
.btn-enter:hover {
    background: url(../images/plank-36736_960_720.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 24%;
    width:55%;
    height: 20%;
    border:none;
    background-color:none;
}
.btn-enter:active {
    background: url(../images/plank-36736_960_720.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 24%;
    width:50%;
    height: 20%;
    border:none;
    background-color:none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-enter"></button>
```

Comment: My own answer: Delete this part of class button "btn-default"

Comment: and add this properties on css class button:-webkit-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;

Answer (score 0):

You can use outline:0;

```
.btn-enter {
    background: url('http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/MatRandom_12.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 24%;
    width:55%;
    height: 20%;
    border:none;
    background-color:none;
   outline:0;
}
.btn-enter:hover {
    background: url(http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/MatRandom_12.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 24%;
    width:55%;
    height: 20%;
    border:none;
    background-color:none;

}
.btn-enter:active {
    background: url(http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/MatRandom_12.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 24%;
    width:50%;
    height: 20%;
    border:none;
    background-color:none;
}
```